# Schengen Visa Sponsorship for group

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, visa-sponsors

Me and my husband wants to visit France and Italy for tourism from India and are applying as a group. Can anyone tell what all documents are required if we want to show me as the sponsor of the whole trip? How much balance do we need to show?

Comment: To understand the policy and visa of the country, first, you need to make sure of your entry point. Which country are you planning to enter first? You have to make the document as per that country.

Comment: @Udhy, both are Schengen countries, so the question would be about the *main destination* of the trip, not the point of entry.

Answer (score 1):

They ask about money because they want to know if you are genuine tourists and not immigrants. A tourist can afford the trip. Each member of the group has to explain where the money for the trip comes from, and show his or her finances. For normal tourists, travel expenses are a luxury. Their travel expenses are a reasonable part of their annual income.

- Your husband will explain that you pay because your are his wife. That's entirely normal in a family.
- You will explain that your pay for both of you and how you can afford that.

The key thing is a **stable, documented income** which is greater than your **reasonable, documented expenses** from both your and your husband's account. This is much more important than the balance on the account.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum subsistence requirements are published here https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25.pdf

The reference amount for adequate means of subsistence for the planned duration of stay in France is €65 per day per individual or €120 if no proof of accommodation is provided. For Italy, the subsistence requirement depends on the length of stay.

As @o.m. states in their answer, merely being able to show that you have the required minimum is not the only financial aspect of an application that visa-issuing authorities consider.